# Why is glCheckFramebufferStatus always 36054 for GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT on OpenGL ES 3.1+?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es

I render the color `(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0)` and depth `(GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT)` of my scene into a **FBO**, which works fine on PC with **OpenGL 4+**.

But on my Smartphone with **OpenGL ES 3.1+** I always get for the depth via `glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)` the `status = 36054`.

```
glGenTextures(1, &m_textCol);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textCol);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, wth, hgt, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glGenTextures(1, &m_textDepth);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textDepth);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, wth, hgt, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

GLuint framebuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textCol, 0);
GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER); always 36053 -> ok

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textDepth, 0);
status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER); // always 36054 -> not ok
```

I tried it also with

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, wth, hgt, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

but no change.

Has maybe someone an idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Section 9.4 of the OpenGL ES3.1 specification discusses depth buffer completeness. It links to a table on page 156 that states which internal texture formats (third parameter to glTexImage2D) are allowable for depth attachments. These are `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16`, `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24` and `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F`.

Comment: Thxs Botje for your infos! I tried it now with different smartphones and settings for the third parameter (GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F) of glTexImage2D, but it only works on half, although all of them have opengl es 3.0+. So I will try it now with a second color buffer, which will hopefully works more save.

Comment: Don't forget to try the combined depth+stencil formats too. Even if you don't need the stencil part.

Comment: yeah, that was the reason, now it works! (internal format: GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, Format: GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, Type: GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8
https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml

Comment: Alright, good to know. Let me write that up as an answer so other people can find it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status 36054 is `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT`.

If we look at Section 9.4 of the OpenGL ES3.1 specification, it lists the following valid `internalFormat` values for depth attachments:

- `DEPTH_COMPONENT16`
- `DEPTH_COMPONENT24`
- `DEPTH_COMPONENT32F`
- `DEPTH24_STENCIL8`
- `DEPTH32F_STENCIL8`

Note that the last two also contain a stencil part. You can use these for the depth component and ignore the stencil attachment if you do not need it. Especially `DEPTH24_STENCIL8` has a good chance of being widely supported.